# sidebar is not a function error

Tags: jquery, sidebar, semantic-ui

I'm trying to get the most basic sidebar example running using examples from [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/definition). Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sidebar.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./css/sidebar.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="ui right vertical menu sidebar">
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">bar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    Your site's actual content
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This shows no sidebar; when I type `$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle')` into the developer console I get this error:

```
VM387:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidebar is not a function(…)
```

Using Chrome 49 on Windows 8.

How do I get the sidebar to show correctly?

Comment: First off, in the network tab, are you getting a 200 OK status code from the sidebar js file?

Comment: Plz check the path of js file included. Are you sure it is in the css folder?

Comment: @BenSewards yes, resources are loading correctly.

Comment: @NateGlenn Could be that you're not including the Jquery lib

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan You're right. I thought it was included, since `$('.ui.sidebar')` didn't throw an error. Now that this is working, it looks completely crazy though. The entire page except for the line where "Your site's actual content" is is all grayed out.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. The formatting stuff is a separate issue.

Comment: @NateGlenn Thanks, but I think it's just fine to put my small answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Other than not including jquery first as a dependency, as stated in the comments, I would not suggest using this plug-in given it's current state, lack of documentation, and inability to use without certain external resources. Here's a working jsfiddle example below based off the demo site:

https://jsfiddle.net/1cthL39a/8/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="wrapper jsc-sidebar-content jsc-sidebar-pulled">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="icon-menu link-menu jsc-sidebar-trigger"></a>
    </nav>
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-header">
            <h1 class="headline"><span class="headline-main">Sidebar</span>JS</h1>
            <p class="version">v 0.2.0</p>
            <p>SidebarJS is a jQuery plugin for side navigation.</p>
            <ul class="btn-list">
                <li><a href="http://github.com/makotot/sidebar" class="btn">View on Github</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://github.com/makotot/sidebar/releases/0.2.0" class="btn">Download</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-body">
            <div class="main-content-body-inner">
                <h2>Public API</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>.push()</h3>
                        <p><a href="#" id="api-push">Open</a> Sidebar content from JavaScript.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>.pull()</h3>
                        <p><a href="#" id="api-pull">Close</a> Sidebar content from JavaScript.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>

        <nav class="sidebar jsc-sidebar" id="jsi-nav" data-sidebar-options="">
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
        <li><a href="./" class="current">SidebarJS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/makotot/sidebar/">View on Github</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/makotot/sidebar/releases">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Notice how many external resources have to be included to get this thing to work.

Comment: I don't think you're using the same library as me. I'm using Semantic UI's sidebar, and you're using a JQuery sidebar plugin.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time. I could probably formulate a better answer if you update your question in regards to your latest comment about the page not rendering properly.